# What is the current state of the Ubuntu Professional certification?

Tags: canonical

I've heard the Ubuntu Professional certification is no longer offered, although the course can be purchased here: http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=533

Is this true? After studying the course, is there no exam or certification given any more?

Comment: This question made me curious myself, so I sent an email to Canonical support asking for further clarification.  When they respond I'll post what they had to say.

Comment: Thanks, have done the same, will post too if they get back.

Comment: Instead of waiting any longer, I have decided to do the CompTIA Linux+ Powered by LPI exams instead. If I pass the two CompTIA exams and get a certificate, it automatically makes you eligible for a certification in LPIC-1, and after you get that, it automatically makes you eligible for a certification with Novell. I have confirmed this from the LPI directly. CompTIA Linux+ > LPIC-1 > Novell CLA. Please see these 3 links: http://goo.gl/w1f3r, http://goo.gl/2Z8nw, http://goo.gl/Zt6iY. You only have to pass the CompTIA exams to get all those certifications (confirmed).

Comment: Hate to be a wet blanket here but what are these worth in terms of your pay?

Comment: Part of me wants to have these as I get more involved with Linux and want these to show for it. Also at work, we have started using Linux more and more and they know I have a real interest for it and suggested I take a course of any sort. I chose Linux and they were happy to help pay for the exams. Not sure if it will directly involve pay but I get to learn an area I'm genuinely interested in and possibly have it paid for. Good for a CV too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just received a response from Canonical, and it stated that in October 2010 they discontinued the Ubuntu Professional course and it was  replaced it with a course that isn't tied to any certification.

They also let me know that while they are not offering any sort of certification at the moment, that they are working towards producing their own certification process that will be ready sometime after Summer 2012.

Comment: I hope so! I want one,Because i use ubuntu, plus its fun to show off to people!! lol

Comment: It's almost time. Summer 2012 ;)

Comment: And now it's almost Summer 20... 22.

Answer (score 4):

I am going to ask the same questions and give the same suggestions as I did [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/is-cloudera-hadoop-certification-worth-the-investment)

**Will this certification give you anything beyond personal satisfaction?**

Before you start down the road of getting a certification you should find out whether or not it's actually worth anything.  The only reason that I see for you to get a certification is because someone else pays for it.

So start by answering the following questions:

1. Are there Jobs requiring Ubuntu certifications?
2. Do they pay more then the ones without it?

If not then the certification might be only for personal satisfaction.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the certification that gives the option of using Ubuntu for the test is the [Linux Foundation Certified SysAdmin (LFCS)](http://training.linuxfoundation.org/certification/lfcs) which gives the user the option of CentOS, openSUSE and Ubuntu. In the case of Ubuntu, it uses the latest LTS which is 14.04.

The test is very complete but you can get a bit of basic training using the [EDX LFS101x: Linux Foundation Introduction to Linux Course](https://courses.edx.org/courses/LinuxFoundationX/LFS101x/2T2014/info) which, for a limited time only, if you finish the course and pass the final exam, it gives a 100$ coupon for the LFCS course.

Another way of gaining the 100$ is in the following [Ubuntu-news-team](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-news-team) Mailing List post which mentions a 100$ bonus off the LFCS for all Ubuntu lovers:

**$100 off Linux Foundation Certification for Ubuntu Members**
https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-news-team/2014-October/002086.html

This are of course focused or give the option of using Ubuntu as the base OS. Other exams like the LPIC of CompTIA+ are more general when it comes to which distro to use.

Comment: I would also recommend Linux Foundation Linux Certification: http://training.linuxfoundation.org/certification

Answer (score 2):

The [Certified Ubuntu Engineer](https://ubuntu.com/cube) (CUBE) is a professional endorsement indicating mastery of Ubuntu. You need to pass 15 microcerts to earn your CUBE qualification.

The program is currently in Beta stage, seeking participants for beta test.

Answer (score 0):

I really think you'd be better off getting the LPIC-1 certification. From what I heard recently on the Linux Action show, and I believe they have a good point, the only distro cert that is worth anything in enterprise at the moment is Red hat. Even then, they say LPIC is just as good.