# Is there such a thing as a Ubuntu Certified Engineer?

Tags: certification, training

I am looking for certification on Ubuntu server technology or possibly Debian (as long as its supplied by Canonical, is that even possible?) which Ubuntu is based on.

Is there such a thing provided by Canonical? In what regions are these services available? Can someone get Ubuntu training and certification the same way Red Hat and other companies supply? Where can I get more information on this matter?

Comment: They stoped it ? :| , I saw cource info in canonical website last year ,but now I can't see it

Comment: Related / Similar (But Different, not to mention I consider the question this comment is on abandoned, but this related one is more recent):  [Are there any Ubuntu Online Courses/training programs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/648310/are-there-any-ubuntu-online-courses-training-programs)

Comment: @ThomasW. Why? Dont see the reason one questions is the same as the other, at all.

Comment: @BrunoPereira [go read Meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14175/duplicate-question-versus-updated-answers-regarding-certification)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this point, no.  Not possible.

There is a wiki [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EngineerCertification).  The issue is that at the very end of the first part of non-header text it states 'The below information is obsolete.'.

If you click the link for up to date information, it directs you to the Ubuntu Support page, which seems to me to be about paid support, not training.

Answer (score 17):

It is actually called **Ubuntu Certified Professional** .

The initial [Ubuntu Certification was Announced in 2006](http://www.ubuntu.com/news/ubuntucert) jointly with  Linux Professional Institute (LPI) for Ubuntu certification exam  ,but later as [Officially announced here in 2010](http://www.canonical.com/news/independent-certified-professional)

> "We are really excited to support the **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS** release with a
> **fresh course and certification programme**," said Billy Cina, Director
> of Training at Canonical. "Having delivered hundreds of courses over
> the last four years, we listened to the requests from training
> partners and students for more Ubuntu-specific content. We have
> responded and are confident that the change will benefit students
> globally. This will also enable us to move from a multiple-choice- to
> a 'Live labs'-type exam which is entirely web-based, testing students'
> ability and Ubuntu skills far more effectively."...
>
> ...The **Ubuntu Certified Professional course is designed for system administrators**
> required to deploy Ubuntu into an office environment, a trend that is
> expected to accelerate with the release of Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. Students
> are not required to have any previous Linux experience but IT/system
> administration experience is a must. **The course lasts for five days in
> a classroom or self-paced via e-learning**. The exams will last 60-90
> minutes and be delivered at **Ubuntu Training Partner** facilities or
> anywhere with a secure broadband connection ...

But the links are **dead** on this page

and also [noted by h-online here](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Canonical-announces-an-Ubuntu-certification-scheme-986735.html) says

> **Canonical** has announced that it will offer its **own certification**
> programme for **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS** and that graduates will be entitled to
> claim an '**Ubuntu Certified Professional**' certification....
>
> The joint programme with the LPI had been very successful, but there
> was great demand for a **pure Ubuntu certification**. Now that the new
> **Long Term Support version** is nearing completion and release, Canonical
> has decided to **start its own certification programme** and offers an
> **online pre-training assessment** to determine if the programme is
> suitable for the prospective candidate.

The **test** can be taken here provided you have an **Launchpad account**

[**Pre-training assessment: Ubuntu Professional**](https://forms.canonical.com/assessment/)

According to [**this**](https://lists.launchpad.net/canonical-website-editors/msg00436.html) ,a **bug was filed for missing Certification page** , but the [**Training Exam page missing**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/588403) bug page doesn't exist any more .

The syllabus or contents covered in the course can be briefly seen [**here**](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ubuntu-user-community/ooVaiUkC640)

---

**Current Scenario** - No formal announcement regarding the present **Course Activity Standing** has been made yet , so contacting the respective

[**Training Team**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Training/Contacts) at **#ubuntu-training on irc.freenode.net** at the [Training wiki Home page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Training) or through

[**Ubuntu-training-community mailing list**](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-training-community) for Official answer would be a feasible and appropriate  Idea.

---

**EDIT:** Further at [Ubuntu Advantage Knowledge](http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/ubuntu-advantage/knowledge) they mention about training

> **Skills training**
>
> **Ubuntu Advantage** offers training for **systems administrators and end
> users training** so you can get the most out of your Ubuntu desktops and
> servers. It also provides **online training courses** so you can **boost
> in-house skills quickly and easily**.
>
> **All training courses** included with Ubuntu Advantage are structured in
> modules, allowing you to take different modules when it suits you, and
> revisit the course to complete any remaining modules when you have
> more time.

And at [Ubuntu Advantage](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=41)

> **Knowledge**: access to exclusive technical articles from Canonical's
> Knowledge Base and **formal training**

while browsing through [Server Support](http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/support/server/support-life-cycles) they mention Training at the Bottom as

[image]

Training link takes you to support page .

**Bottom-line** they seem to offer Training courses currently through [**Ubuntu Advantage**](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=41) only as Paid Enterprise service.

**P.S.** : *I may be wrong about the new info , if so then please feel free to edit it.*

Comment: The training team appears to be dead.  I think the answer to this is now "No, the program was abandoned".

Comment: See also; http://askubuntu.com/q/87445/178596

Answer (score 10):

I just took the
[Pre-training assessment: Ubuntu Professional](https://forms.canonical.com/assessment/)
and got the following reply mail from them:

> Dear Saji Nediyanchath,
>
> Thank you very much for taking part in the pre-training assessment.
>
> Your score is 9,
>
> Visit: www.ubuntu.com/training for more information.
>
> Best regards and good luck The Ubuntu Training Team

And when we visit:
[www.ubuntu.com/training](http://www.ubuntu.com/training)
it redirects to:
http://www.ubuntu.com/support
And that page has no information related to any certification courses.
`So I'm sure that no such certification exists now.`

**Update:**

Now Ubuntu offers training for sysadmins and devops engineers to become Ubuntu OpenStack experts.

**Ref:** https://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/training

Answer (score 0):

Honestly at this point your best bet is to test for the LPIC 2.  It's designed to cover all major Linux Distros, and very little outside the rpm section isn't useful on Ubuntu.  (The package questions include deb and rpm questions.)  It's a mostly a multiple choice test with some short answer.  Unlike the RHCE which is hands on.  Some people say the RHCE is better, but a lot of experinced admins find the LPIC tests harder.  In a hands on test you can use the man pages and don't need remember the exact command line options or the syntax of config file you edit a couple of times a year.