# Can the Ubuntu Certification help professionally?

Tags: certification

If I do Ubuntu certification, how much can it help me professionally, especially when it comes to applying for jobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Note:** The current state of any Canonical-provided "Ubuntu Certification" is unknown. Please read the below question/answer in detail for more information:
>
> [***Is there such a thing as a Ubuntu Certified Engineer?***](https://askubuntu.com/a/167802/58612)

As [this brief syllabus](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ubuntu-user-community/ooVaiUkC640) shows, the *Ubuntu Certified Professional* course was based on the standard [Linux Professional Institute](http://lpi.org/) [**LPIC-1**](http://lpi.org/linux-certifications/programs/lpic-1) certification.

Also known as the "Junior Level Linux Certification", the requirements for UCP/LPIC-1 include:

> 1. Install and configure Ubuntu desktop systems
> 2. Perform routine administration tasks: boot and shut down the system,
>      manage user accounts and file systems, and maintain system security
> 3. Configure network connectivity and key network services
> 4. Work productively at the Linux command line

If you do not possess a certification that includes such a skillset, then yes, the Ubuntu Certification (or LPIC-1) may possibly help you in applying for positions as an *entry-level* Ubuntu/Linux System Administrator.

Afterwards, you should look at the more advanced LPIC-2 and LPIC-3 certifications to be able to apply to jobs beyond "entry-level".

Comment: ,what about RHCE ?

Comment: @GrSr: RHCE is offered currently, but note that you need to be an RHCSA first. It can potentially help you more in enterprises that use RHEL -- which at this time is probably more than those which use Ubuntu Server.

Comment: but i heard that RHCE we can try with out getting RHCSA . is it possible ?